# Notepad++ fails to load the plugins folder

Tags: notepad++

Notepad++ plugins folder does not load properly.

I updated Notepad++ to v8.6.2. I use Windows 10 Pro, 64 bit. I have found that if I open Notepad++ directly using its exe file, then plugins fails to load, all I get is a message "Open Plugins Folder". If I click that message I get an empty plugins folder attached to another working directory. However, if I right click on a file and choose "Edit with Notepad++", plugins loads properly and I get the list of plugins as expected. Does this sound like a problem with my computer and installation, or is this a common problem, or intended behavior, with Notepad++?

Comment: This surely isn't intended behaviour. My Notepad++ v8.6.2 with 9 installed plugins starts just fine (on Windows 11). Maybe it's related to one of your installed plugins. Try to disable all plugins in the Plugins Admin (_Plugins -> Plugins Admin..._) and see if Notepad++ starts normal again. If so try to reenable the plugins one by one. Possibly you can identify a broken plugin.

Comment: You might also try the `-noPlugin` command line argument. See [the manual](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/command-prompt/#help-usage).

Comment: The -noPlugin arg did not help. Trial and error has worked. I uninstalled Notepad++, cleaned the registry using CCleaner, deleted any file with Notepad++ in the name using ZTreeW64 and reinstalled v8.6.2.  It appears to have solved the problem. I had reinstalled before, but I had not gone through the computer looking for remaining file with Notepad++ in the name. Thanks for your suggestions.